# python 2.4.3, unable to use check_output

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm a Java & C programmer who is learning Python.  I'm writing a Python program which needs to issue Linux commands and then capture the output.  (Output should be a single line which python can store in a string... I hope.)  I am on an older machine, running Python 2.4.3, and as far as I can see, the **check_output** call should do what I need.

Trouble is, python doesn't recognize **check_output**.  Here's my prototype code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
print "Current Python Version::  ", (sys.version)

import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output    # <<<<<<<< error here!

output = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-1', '|', 'grep', 'somefile.txt'])
print 'Have %d bytes in output' % len(output)
print output
```

Output is:

```
[Linux]$ python myCode.py
Current Python Version::   2.4.3 (#1, Apr 14 2011, 20:41:59)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myCode.py", line 7, in ?
    from subprocess import check_output
ImportError: cannot import name check_output
[Linux]$
```

I'm using the below website as a doc guide; in fact, the last three lines of my code are more-or-less directly copied from this site's example:

https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/#capturing-output

The doc says **check_output** is valid in Python 2.4 and up, so I should be okay.  And yet my Python interpreter doesn't understand **check_output**.

So... what to make of this?  It looks like my version is okay and Python can access **subprocess** but not **check_output**.  Do I need to ask the admin to install a library or something?  Or am I not importing the call correctly?

Also:  I'm sort of assuming that **check_output** is the call I want here to capture a one-line output from my Linux command.  Does that seem okay?

Thanks!

Comment: I think those docs are wrong. `check_output` is new in Python 2.7, as [these docs say][1]. You'll need to upgrade your Python version.


  [1]: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: workaround: use `Popen` and check return code. if != 0 raise an exception.

Comment: Upgrade your ancient python version!

Comment: @Chris_Rands The doc is wrong???  Aw, man, that's disappointing.  Thanks for pointing that out.